# Kinetic energy of disc pivoting about its edge

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics

Suppose we have a disc of radius $R$ suspended vertically from a pivot on its edge. This disc is then given an initial angular displacement $θ$ and permitted to freely swing without friction.

A problem arises when I attempt to calculate the maximum velocity (at equilibrium, when $ θ$ is zero).

$$Mgh=\frac{1}{2}Mv^2$$
$$Mg(R-Rcos\theta)=\frac{1}{2}Mv^2$$
$$v=\sqrt{2gR(1-cos\theta)}$$

Using angular quantities, however, we have

$$ Mgh = \frac{1}{2}I\omega^2$$
$$Mg(R-Rcos\theta) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}MR^2 + MR^2)\omega^2$$
$$\omega = \sqrt{\frac{4g}{3R}(1-cos\theta)}$$

There is an obvious inconsistency between the results when we manipulate them using $\omega R = v$ to find the linear velocity from the angular result

$$v= \sqrt{\frac{4gR}{3}(1-cos\theta)}$$

My textbook derives the maximum velocity using angular quantities. My question is - is there not a translational component to the kinetic energy as well? (The centre of mass is certainly not stationary) Why is the first result incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

The translational component is already taken into account by your use of the parallel axes theorem to derive the moment of inertia for a disk rotating about its edge. But if you *just* use translation you are not accounting for the rotation of the disk... At the lowest point in the arc the points are not all moving in the same direction: some move faster, some move slower, some have vertical components. None of that is taken into account if you assume only translation- but it *is* when you treat the disk as rotating (which it is, after all).